# How to put absolutely positioned DIV behind the SPAN or relatively positioned DIV?

Tags: css, z-index, html

Is it possible to put absolutely positioned DIV behind the SPAN or relatively positioned DIV? It seems to me that z-index does not affect SPANs etc.

Comment: z-index works only on fixed, relative & absolute position elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use `span { display: block; }`.

I think that will place the `span` above the absolutely positioned div. And the `z-index` should also be defined. Also, I usually don't use `position: relative` for a `div` that has to be placed below other `div's`.